# Spacebars syntax for embedded documents

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I have the following schema for a company's financial statement information:

```
FinancialsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
revenue: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Revenue",
    min: 0,
    optional: true
}
});

TimeSchema = new SimpleSchema({
period: {
    type: String,
    label: "Period",
    optional: true
},
financials: {
    type: FinancialsSchema,
    optional: true
}
});

CompanySchema = new SimpleSchema({
name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Company Name"
},
time: {
    type: TimeSchema,
    optional: true
}
});

Companies.attachSchema(CompanySchema);
```

I am trying to reference the LTM, FY+1 and FY+2 revenue figures using spacebars to display in a table.  I already have the following in my collection and tested through the console that the revenue and EBITDA numbers have both been captured under LTM.

```
    Companies.insert({
    name: "Example",
    sector: "Industrial",
    status: "Public",
    time: {
        period: "LTM",
        financials: {
            revenue: "200",
            ebitda: "100"
        }
    }
});
```

I would have thought {{period("LTM").revenue}} would work but have tried dozens of variations and can't get the figures to appear in the table.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to review the [Spacebars Readme](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md), because I don't believe `{{period("LTM").revenue}}` is a valid spacebars tag. Functions are called by separating the function name from its arguments by a space, like so: `{{functionName arg1 arg2}}`.

To get what you're after, you'll need to first get the copany of interest, probably with a helper that returns `Companies.findOne({period: "LTM"})`.

Once you have the Company of interest as the data context, you'll need to use  `{{time.financials.revenue}}` and `{{time.financials.ebitda}}` to get the revenue and EBITDA values. The way you've written your schema, each company entry can only have one revenue and EBITDA value, and they are stored in the time.financials object.

Comment: Thanks Thaum. I had left out the part if my code showing that the company of interest is already in context, so that part is addressed. As for the schema, is each value unique?  I had originally written my schema using ebitdaLtm, ebitdaFy1 and ebitdaFy2. But I thought that breaking out the period into a level above the value would allow for better screening (e.g., find all LTM values). Them the spacebars reference would show the EBITDA associated with a period of "LTM". Is that use incorrect or have I coded it incorrectly?

Comment: Got it now - realized how my schema was only giving me one chance to fill in the period, so could not have different figures for revenue, etc.  Broke out LTM, FY1 and FY2 as individual schemas, each referencing FundamentalsSchema for the financials.  Works great now